# Find Directories with particular tree structure

Tags: bash, shell

I want to find directories in the file system which has a particular tree structure.

The tree structure I am trying to locate is as follows:

```sh
.
├── docker
│   └── build.sh
├── include
├── config.yaml
└── src
```

Would like to get some help regarding this.

Comment: `src` is a file or directory or anything?

Comment: src is a directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "$1" && [ -e docker -a -e docker/build.sh -a -e include -a -e config.yaml -a -e src ]' -- {} \; -print
```

Depending on if the entry should be a directory or a file, change the `-e` to `-d` or `-f` according to [man test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test).

- `find`
- `-type d` only directories
- `-exec sh -c '.....' -- {} \;` - for each directory run

  - `cd "$1"` - cd into the direcotry
  - `[ -e docker -a -e docker/build.sh -a -e include -a -e config.yaml -a -e src ]` - check if the proper directory structure exists
- if it does, `find` takes shells exit status and executes `-print` only if shell exited with success

Comment: There is probably something more performant if you find dirs of name docker then explore only from there with the -exec shell

Comment: Like: `find 2>/dev/null . -type d -name docker -exec sh -c 'cd "$1" && [ -e build.sh -a -e ../include -a -e ../config.yaml -a -e ../src ]' -- {} \; -printf '%h\n'`